# how to call method inside $http body angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to call `editopenComponentModal` in my other method its show error `angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'editopenComponentModal' of undefined`

```
   EditCurrentJob(job) {

          this.$http.put(properties.job_path + "/"+job.job_id).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.current_job =  response.data;
            this.editopenComponentModal();

         }, 
          function errorCallback(response) {

          });
}

     editopenComponentModal() {
        var modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open({
          animation: this.animationsEnabled,
          template: require('./Report/editsubmittedinformation.html'),
          scope: this.$scope,
          size: 'lg'
        });
        this.$scope.modalInstance = modalInstance;

        return modalInstance.result;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function references for that purpose, jopefully this will help you out.

```
var vm = this;
vm.editopenComponentModal = editopenComponentModal;
function EditCurrentJob(job) {

      $http.put(properties.job_path + "/"+job.job_id).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        vm.current_job =  response.data;
        vm.editopenComponentModal();

     }, 
      function errorCallback(response) {

      });
}

 function editopenComponentModal() {
    var modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open({
      animation: this.animationsEnabled,
      template: require('./Report/editsubmittedinformation.html'),
      scope: this.$scope,
      size: 'lg'
    });
    this.$scope.modalInstance = modalInstance;

    return modalInstance.result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a modal after $http.put request then  use.

```
  $('#success').modal();
```

here success is the id.

Answer (score 0):

Add `var that = this` above the `this.$http.put(`

Then change:

`this.current_job =  response.data;`

`this.editopenComponentModal();`

To:

`that.current_job =  response.data;`

`that.editopenComponentModal();`

Explanation:
`this` inside the callback has different context, so you need to save the desired `this` to a variable which can be used there.

Here you can read the better explanation:
[How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: ReferenceError: that is not defined